# Generate random numbers and write to text file

Tags: python, file, random

So I have to generate 100 random numbers between 1 and 100 and write them into a txt file with enter (\n) between the numbers.

Next task is to read back this txt file, count how many numbers are between 20 and 80, then write the amount to the STDOUT. Write these numbers (the ones that are between 20 and 80) into another txt file with a comma in between the numbers.

This is the code I have come up with, kinda works, but I'm sure there is a simpler and shorter way to do it. Plus it doesn't work right for some reason, because it writes some (not every) number below 10 into the file (also counts them):

```
import random

f = open("eredmenyek_nyers.txt", "w")
for i in range(100):
    randomlist = random.randint(1,100)
    f.write(str(randomlist) + '\n')
f.close()

db=0
f = open("eredmenyek_nyers.txt", "r")
f2 = open("eredmenyek_szort.txt", "w")
szamok = f.read()
ezt = szamok.split("\n")
xxx=len(ezt)
print(ezt)
i=0
db=0

for xxx in ezt:
    if '80' > ezt[i]:
        if ezt[i] > '20':
            db+=1
            f2.write(str(ezt[i]) + ',')
    i+=1
print("Ennyi 20 és 80 közötti szám van ebben a listában:",db)
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: When you compare "5" with "25", you are comparing **strings**. And just like "Eve" is between "Charles" and "Franziska", "5" is between "25" and "80". This is the so-called *lexicographic* comparison. You need instead to do a comparison between *numbers*.

Comment: use `with` to make file handling simpler. Name your variables correctly: `randomlist` is not a list. Use `readlines()` instead of `read` + `split`. Use `20 < a < 80` for the comparison instead of two comparisons. Remove unused code `xxx=len(ezt)`. Use `int(ezt[i])` to convert a string to an integer. So many thing to do here ...

Comment: You are using string comparisons instead of integer. You meant to write: `if 80 > int(ezt[i]):` etc

Comment: But how do I do that?
This is the list of numbers that I get, and have to somehow sort between 20 and 80, but if i just put 20 and 80 in the if it gives me TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.
['3', '80', '36', '14', '12', '30', '22', '68', '31', '87', '81', '77', '35', '89', '63', '64', '19', '37', '35', '51', '65', '66', '54', '78', '7', '95', '91']
How do I get that list to be ints?

Comment: Simplest way would be to write to both files at once instead of writing and reading the first file, conditionally writing to the second file obviously

Comment: @quamrana 
I have tried that multiple times, but  I just get this error: 
if 80 > int(ezt[i]):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @ThomasWeller In the tasks that I got the hint said to use split. Didn't really hear about with so don't really know how to use it. Converting to int gives me an error as mentioned in another comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of problem due to string being compared to integers is resolved. Below code will do what the expectation is. But, as you mentioned in the question, first is to write 100 numbers to a file, **post that** read the file, print in STDOUT, **post that** write the numbers between 20 and 80 into another file... this appears as a sequence of events. You can write to both files and STDOUT in one for loop itself, if that is not an issue. I am updating so that the sequence of actions are done one after another - as is mentioned in your question.

Replace the **2nd for loop** with this code....

```
for item in ezt:
    if item != '': # To handle last /n which will be a blank 
        if int(item) < 80 and int(item) > 20:
            db+=1
            f2.write(item + ',')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Next I have to make a UI for this :)

Comment: That's good. If this answered your question, pls accept it by clicking on the tick mark below the response so that this gets closed/accepted

Answer (score 0):

> ... This is the code I have come up with, kinda works, but I'm sure there is a simpler and shorter way to do it. ...

You could actually do this a bit compacter, with [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
from random import randint

with open("numbers.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(f"{randint(1, 100)}\n" for _ in range(100))

with open("numbers.txt", "r") as fin,\
     open("filtered_numbers.txt", "w") as fout:
    numbers = [n for n in map(int, fin) if 20 < n < 80]
    print(f"Found {len(numbers)} numbers between 20 and 80.")
    fout.write(",".join(map(str, numbers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to load the file into a list. Python has nice tools for working with lists, so we can iterate the list and generate a new list of the items that pass the test, then get the length of that new list an write it out to a new file.

To make it easy to read and diagnose, it's sometimes useful to break the problem into small pieces as well.

```
import random

""" Generate intial file of random numbers.
"""
f = open("file1.txt", "w")
for i in range(100):
    f.write(str(random.randint(1,100)) + "\n")
f.close()


""" Read file items into a list. This will make other operations
    easier.
"""
num_list = []
f = open("file1.txt", "r")
while True:
    next_line = f.readline()
    if len(next_line) == 0:
        break
    num_list.append(int(next_line))
f.close()


""" Create new list and append items >=20 and <=80.
"""
short_list = []
for i in num_list:
    if 20 <= i <= 80: short_list.append(i)


""" Output number of items in short list. Convert to a string so 
    [] can be removed, then write to file.
"""
print("Number of items:", len(short_list))
f = open("file2.txt", "w")
string = (str(short_list)).strip('[]')
f.write(string + "\n")
f.close()
```